# Copying MySite Trending Tags Webpart

Tags: web-part, mysite, tags, sitefeed

I am wanting to replicated the 'Trending tags' and the 'I'm following' webparts that you typically find on MySite pages. It's to accompany an already existing 'SiteFeed' webpart.

I can't find either as standalone webparts and I was wonder if I needed to do something to be able to access them, or whether there was something else with similar functionality that I could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to the MySites’ landing page and put this page into edit mode. Then select the Trending #Tags web part and choose Export… This will allow you to download the web part as a DWP file.